# Where can i download sources for agilo for scrum?

Tags: scrum, trac

I looked inside agilo for scrum web site ([agilo for scrum](http://www.agile42.com/en/agile-info-center/) and i can't find its source code although they say its open source.

can anyone say where can i download its sources from?
tanks

Comment: Besides the fact that Agilo appears to be closed source, this question  seems quite off topic to me - SO is not a "find this download for me" site. Flagged accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is it supposed to say that Agilo is OS? Actually, their TOS state quite the opposite:

> All Software is the sole property of Agilo Software GmbH and all rights not expressly granted to you in this EULA are reserved by us. Agilo Software is the owner of title, copyright, and other intellectual property. The software is licensed, not sold.

Comment: what about this: "It's free and open source " from this url: http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/AgiloForScrum

Comment: It appears that this has changed. Also, try contacting agilo software's support.

Comment: i found that its name  was updated for agilo for trac and it is open source i managed to download its sources via: http://www.agilofortrac.com/en/

Comment: By my knowledge, open source does not contradict proprietary code. It just means that you can and are allowed to download and read the source code, and use it (as a reference) for writing your own code, e.g. plugins, even though you might not be allowed to copy parts of the code into your own source.